# capturing camera in electric and groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, image, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to change my code for capturing images from electric to groovy and find that CvBridge has gone. Finding http://answers.ros.org/question/9765/how-to-convert-cvmat-to-sensor_msgsimageptr/?answer=14282#post-id-14282 and http://answers.ros.org/question/60279/sensor_msgscvbridgecvtoimgmsg-in-groovy/ they seem to offer a solution but also raises questions about the use of some variables that are just used without visible declaration. My current code:

`sensor_msgs::CvBridge cvbridge; image = cvbridge.imgMsgToCv(msgs_im, "bgr8");`.

Can somebody give an explanation ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103601/capturing-camera-in-electric-and-groovy/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2013-11-21**:
My point is that in the first answer in that link i and ci are being used without explanation. That makes it for me hard to understand how it exactly happens. If you can tell me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your second link would seem to answer your own question ... have you tried it? What didn't work?

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0